# How to remove left-over files from an Homebrew installation

Tags: bash, path, homebrew, osx-yosemite, macos-monterey

My current homebrew has its files installed in /opt/homebrew which is correct. However, I have several hundred leftover homebrew files in /usr/local/Cellar which are still symlinked to in /usr/local/bin, e.g.:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 xxx  admin         32 Apr 30  2020 idn2 -> ../Cellar/libidn2/2.3.0/bin/idn2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 xxx  admin         32 Apr 30  2020 wget -> ../Cellar/wget/1.20.3_2/bin/wget
lrwxr-xr-x  1 xxx  admin         34 Apr 30  2020 mvnyjp -> ../Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/bin/mvnyjp
lrwxr-xr-x  1 xxx  admin         36 Apr 30  2020 mvnDebug -> ../Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/bin/mvnDebug
```

I believe this is from when I switched from an Intel mac to Apple Silicon M1 (note 2020).

/opt/homebrew/bin is before /usr/local/bin in my path

brew doctor has no complaints. brew list does NOT show any of these files or casks at all, and I have tried several variations of brew cleanup without effect.

It's a real mess. What is the best and safest way to clean these up?